# f# inline method chosen principal confusing

Tags: c#, f#, polymorphism, inline

```
type FooBar = FooBar with 
  static member print (a:FooBar) = printfn "%s" "foobar"

type PrintDefault = PrintDefault with
  static member inline print (a:int) = printfn "%s" "int"
  static member inline print (a:string) = printfn "%s" "string"

  static member inline print (a:obj) = printfn "%s" "object" // override others ?

let inline printOrDefault (a:^a, b:^b) =
  ((^a or ^b):(static member print: ^a -> unit) a)

let inline print a =
  printOrDefault (a, PrintDefault)

print 42
print "hello"
print FooBar
print (box 42)
```

doesn't method choosing follow the narrowest principal? but here the `print : obj -> unit` method override others .

```
public static void print<a>(a a)
{
    "Dynamic invocation of print is not supported";
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

if i don't supply the `obj print`, method invoke by `c#` will get an `NotSupportedException`，if i supply the `obj print`, behavior in f# are messed up.

what is the method choose principal here ?

beyond c# interop, if invoke through `printOrDefault` not by `print` , things are correct.

```
print 42 // "object"
print "hello" // "object"
print FooBar // "object"
print (box 42) // "object"

printfn "----------------------------"

printOrDefault (42, PrintDefault) // "int"
printOrDefault ("hello", PrintDefault) // "string"
printOrDefault (FooBar, PrintDefault) // "foobar"
printOrDefault (box 42, PrintDefault) // "object"
```

Comment: F# inline functions are not useful to any language other than F#. Trying to fit C# into this at all is likely to be a fruitless endeavor.

Comment: @ildjarn thx, beyond c# interop .  what if i want `print 42` and `print (box 42)` show different result depend on their type ? seems inline here doesn't help  ?

Comment: Without using some of [@Gustavo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446822/)'s faux-overloading tricks, you need to use methods rather than functions to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Jun - I'm not sure you *can* make `print 42` and `print (box 42)` differentiate based on their type: 42 is an int, a **value** type. If it is used in any context that expects a reference type, it will (as I understand it) be automatically boxed, at which point it has become indistinguishable from `box 42`. Maybe there's a trick you can do with static typing -- I'm unfamiliar with that -- but it seems to me that it will be difficult at best to distinguish an int from a boxed int, since as far as I can tell, F# treats them as almost the same thing and auto-converts them as needed.

Comment: @rmunn  how about result shows **invoke through printOrDefault not by print**

Comment: Then apparently there are some contexts in which it works. As I said, I'm unfamiliar with F#'s static typing system, so you're teaching me new things here. If you come to understand the static typing system better through this exercise, maybe you could write an article about it -- I'd certainly appreciate reading it. But I don't have the knowledge to answer your question here.

Comment: I find cases like this all the time. The behaviour is different because they use different mechanism, one is simply .NET method overloading and the other one is the case when an inline function is created which is immediately resolved to one of the overloads at its definition, instead of deferring the resolution to the calling site. To me this is a bug and it needs to be reported, but it will probably need an RFC to handle properly these cases.

Comment: @rmunn thx anyway  : )

Comment: @Gustavo thx, get it . https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3164

Comment: @Gustavo if this different behavior  because use different mechanism. when i comment `static member inline print (a:obj) = printfn "%s" "object" ` this method, seem `inline print` is **not** created which is immediately resolved to one of the overloads at its definition. it is deferring the resolution to the calling site.  does the `print (a:obj)` method affect the mechanism choosing ?

Comment: Not 100% sure about what is your question, but definitely yes, all overloads affect the resolution, if you take one off or add a new one it might change. Actually I find myself many times adding a 'dummy' overload which is never used, in order to make the resolution behave the way I want. So this is definitely something that must be changed in the compiler but we will have to go through the user voice and suggest a very detailed spec.

Comment: @Gustavo : If/when such a suggestion is ever formally made, I surely hope I find out about it so I can upvote the hell out of it! :-]

Comment: @ildjarn Then I will let you know !